# Jquery $.getScript IF user is on a certain CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I ham using a Javascript snow plug in -> SnowStorm.JS and I'm trying to implement the SnowStorm so that it will only work on one certain CSS only.

I have the basic Style Switcher working in HTML:

```
<b>Change theme:</b> <input type="submit" id = "Winter" class="btn btn-Primary navbar-btn"
          onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('Winter'); return false" name="Winter" value=
          "Winter" /> 
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-Warning navbar-btn" onclick=
          "setActiveStyleSheet('Summer'); return false"  id = "Summer" name="Summer" value="Summer" />
```

In my Jquery / Javscript I have done this:

```
$("#Winter").click(function(){

$.getScript("js/snow.js");

});

$("#Summer").click(function(){

snowStorm.stop() // Kills the Javascript (Otherwise it will run on Summer)

 });
```

I was trying to do it, so if they are on the Winter (Style) then it will get the script "snow.js". And if it's on Summer the ongoing script will stop.

Is there a way to make my code work? Or is there an alternative / why it's not working.

Comment: You should try: `snowStorm.freeze();` and `snowStorm.resume();`

Comment: If i do that,the snow will stay in the same spots  when `SnowStorm.free()` is executed if i switch to the Summer CSS

Comment: Then, how about: `snowStorm.toggleSnow()`

Comment: Tried that, however if the user clicks on the CSS id `#Winter` and they're already on that CSS then it will toggle it again. Which is my main problem. I need to find a way so if they're already on that specific CSS then it will not toggle.